# Can webpack generate a module with exports?

Tags: testing, webpack, es6-modules, esmodules

I was able to create a webpack config to bundle few modules. The generated bundle looks as follows:

```
/* harmony default export */ const subscriptions = ({
... // my stuff
/******/ })()
;
```

I'd like to test the generated bundle so i need to have some `export`s instead of self-invoking function to import it in the test and make sure everything is aliased as expected (so i have correct `resolve.alias` webpack section in my config), smth similar to the following:

```
export const subscriptions = ...
```

Is it possible to instruct webpack to generate it as a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it with the following webpack config:

```
    ...
    output: {
      ...
      library: {type: "module"}
    },
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true
    },
    ...
```